# How can i track views on my website's pages by cookies

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, google-analytics

My website gonna have a lot of pages, URLs would be like

```
http://test.com/abcdse
http://test.com/1gshjj
....
```

I want to track the views on these pages by cookies, I can think of saving the views of each page in view column in database and for checking the user's uniqueness I am thinking of sending cookie "pages_id", which will include the all the ids(separated by commas) of the pages which user has visited, And everytime user visits a new page I need to update that cookie,

That was the solution I was thinking But then I checked other sites(https://links-safety.com/HNpj5K) who track the views, They use cookies named _gid, _ga, etc, And they don't have any long string which saves the page_ids, So then I try to google about these cookies(_gid and _ga) I found they are used by google analytics.js. And then I found many more libraries and methods to track the views,

I am totally confused now, But I have this feeling that it would be very easy to do with some existing library or something, Could someone guide me a little bit to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Just install google analytics. It's a tiny js script and your done. Why try to make something that someone else has done much better?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I am gonna try that, I wasn't sure about that, But now i am, Thanks!

Comment: Should I delete this question?,  I think it doesn't make any sense to anybody else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can think of saving the views of each page in view column in database

Yes. Do that.

Well. Aside from the column. You need a bridge table that connects a user to a page at a time.

> for checking the user's uniqueness I am thinking of sending cookie "pages_id", which will include the all the ids(separated by commas) of the pages which user has visited,

That doesn't tell you anything about the user's uniqueness. That just tells you which pages the user has visited … and it stores the data in the browser where you can't get at it.

Store the data in the database as you originally planned.

> They use cookies named _gid, _ga, etc, And they don't have any long string which saves the page_ids,

No. They have a unique identifier so they can tell one user from another.

> I have this feeling that it would be very easy to do with some existing library or something

Yes. Google Analytics. They even provide the database for you.

Comment: Thanks, Btw you wrote "That doesn't tell you anything about the user's uniqueness"  Why not?, I will check if page_ids cookie already has the id of current page if yes that means that user has visited that page, Anyway i will try google analytics. Thanks

Comment: @beginner — Bob visits Page 1 and gets a page 1 cookie. Alice visits Page 1 and gets a page 1 cookie. Now they have identical cookies. As far as you can tell from the cookies, Alice and Bob are identical.

Comment: Ahh!, that way, but I don't need to know that, I just want to know if the user has already visited the page or not, If not I will increase the view count, If yes i will leave the count as it is,
 Anyway I misunderstood what you were saying, Thanks for your help again :)